# Certificate Authority works in Linux but fails in MacOS

Tags: macos, ssl, certificate, https

I want to create a self-signed root certificate authority, such that the certificates signed by this CA are trusted by the OS which trusts the CA.

After following a couple different guides, I managed to produce certificate authority that works in a Linux machine. However, the same generation process fails when applied to my Mac.

Below is a script (`generate.sh`) to generate the CA and the server certificate:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p ./out

# CA configuration
openssl genrsa -out ./out/CA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 \
    -new \
    -nodes \
    -key ./out/CA.key \
    -sha256 -days 365 \
    -subj "/C=NA/ST=NA/L=NA/O=org/OU=orgunit/CN=special-name"\
    -out ./out/CA.pem

# server certificate
openssl genrsa -out ./out/server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key ./out/server.key \
    -subj "/C=NA/ST=NA/L=NA/O=org/OU=orgunit/CN=special-name"\
    -out ./out/server.csr
    
echo "extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName=DNS:localhost" | openssl x509 -req -in ./out/server.csr \
    -CA ./out/CA.pem \
    -CAkey ./out/CA.key \
    -CAcreateserial \
    -out ./out/server.crt \
    -days 825 \
    -sha256 \
    -extfile /dev/stdin > /dev/null
```

I've spent some time trying to figure out what is happening, but every solution online seems to be different.

Here is the process to generate and test the certificate:

```sh
./generate.sh
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ./out/CA.pem
docker build -t cert-test .
docker run -d -p 443:443 --name cert-test cert-test
curl https://localhost:443
```

The server certificates are loaded to a container made by this Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY ./out/server.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY ./out/server.key /etc/ssl/private

EXPOSE 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

with the accompanying `./nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         localhost;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index   index.html index.html;
    }
}
```

All this is available in [certificate-mess](https://github.com/lidj22/certificate-mess/tree/dev).

**Expected result**: `curl https://localhost:443` returns the nginx welcome page.

**Actual result**: `curl https://localhost:443` does not return the nginx welcome page, instead states the website is insecure/invalid:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Why does this process fail for ios/macos, and how do I resolve it? I've double-checked [Requirements for trusted certificates in iOS 13 and macOS 10.15](https://support.apple.com/en-us/103769),  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only describe how you generate the certificates but not how you actually use these. How did you import these into the trust store, how did you check if it works, what exact errors you get ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich there's quite a bit of scripts and configuration files to run a simple test case, which is why I pointed it to a repository to avoid the post from cluttering. I'll copy and paste it here then.

Comment: updated post for clarity.

Comment: @David: I don't think curl on MacOS will use the system CA store. Use `--cacert` argument instead to specify your CA.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich In the end I need my browsers (ios, safari) on various devices to trust the CAs; I had thought `curl` and python requests `requests.get("https://localhost:443")` are prerequisite tests I can quickly conduct to check whether it works.

Comment: `curl --cacert out/CA.crt https://localhost:443` still reproduces the same error. I'm very confused. Is the issue with my CA/server certificate generation, or with the way I add the CA certificate to my OS?

Comment: You must not use the same subject for CA certificate and server certificate. This is not specific to MacOS. Apart from this change (i.e. replace `CN=special-name` with `CN=CA`) for the CA it works for me on MacOS when testing the generated server certificate with `openssl s_server` and using `curl --cacert ...` as client.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich You are right, I would never have thought that would be the reason... I distinguished the CN for the CA and server, and now curl works. In fact, `curl https://localhost:443` seems to work for me (without need for `--cacert`). I'm going to investigate this and see if I can reproduce this more clearly.

Comment: Strangely, python requests still fails: `import requests; requests.get("https://localhost:443")`.

Comment: I guess in the context of the curl problem, this question is answered. However, the wget, requests, and browsers do not recognize the certificate. This probably means that curl has weaker conditions than the latter in validating a server certificate. I'll probably ask a different question in regards to that.

Comment: @David: It is not about weaker vs. stronger conditions. There is simply not a single trust store which is used by all applications. You might need to make adjustments for each application which trust store to use. For requests you can use the `verify` argument to specify what CA to trust. This is also not specific to MacOS but same mess on Windows and to some extend on Linux too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149901/discussion-between-david-and-steffen-ullrich).